# activator fails to load project after IDE restart (scala, play, intellij idea)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have a small play application (resultful service) and I am using Intellij Idea. My project compiles fine from the IDE, and I could also use activator to compile and run the application. I quit the IDE (while my application was running inside activator). Now activator or sbt cannot load the `build.sbt` file and complain:

```
[MY_APP_FOLDER]/build.sbt:1: error: not found: object play
import play.PlayImport.PlayKeys._
```

I still can compile from within the IDE.

EDIT: I am thinking if there is some sort of cache for activator that could be corrupted for this application? My other application is loaded into activator with no problem.

Comment: can you share your `build.sbt`? The problem probably lies in there.

Comment: You are not running activator from built-in terminal of Intellij?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But as I said, it was compiling fine before, so `build.sbt` is fine. I tried activator from both the built-in and external terminal. But as I posted below, the problem was that the `plugins.sbt` was somehow removed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that somehow the `plugins.sbt` was removed from the project folder. After recovering it, the compilation is successful again.